# Socket not closing when shutting down a thread

Tags: python

In the below code, although the thread seems to be stopping the socket does not seem to be freed. Not sure what mistake I am making.
When I try to start the second time it is throwing an error 'Address already in use'. I looked up a lot of stack overflow suggestions, did not help much.

Here is my code:

```
import threading
import time
import socket

class TCPServer(object):
   def __init__(self):
     self.stop_thread = threading.Event()

   def startServer(self, ip="localhost", port=12345):
     self.ip = ip
     self.port = port
     t = threading.Thread(target=self.server, args=(self.stop_thread, 
                          "stop_event"))
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

   def server(self, stop_event, arg):
     self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
     sock.bind((self.ip, self.port))
     sock.listen(5)
     connection = ""
     while not stop_event.is_set():
       connection, addr = self.sock.accept()
       data = connection.recv(50000)
       if data:
         connection.send(self.response)
     connection.close()
     #Tried with below statements - still fails
     #self.sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
     #self.sock.close()


   def stopServer(self):
     self.stop_thread.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   server = TCPServer()
   server.startServer("localhost", 12345)
   time.sleep(5)
   server.stopServer()
   time.sleep(15)    
   server.startServer("localhost", 12345)
   time.sleep(5)
   server.stopServer()
```

I found a work around by forcefully shutting down the socket in `stopServer()` like below:

```
   def stopServer(self):
     self.stop_thread.set()
     self.sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
     self.sock.close()
```

But I dont think this is a good solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: In any case your thread will have need to complete one connection to finish, even if there is none at the moment.

Comment: There is **no** `self.sock`.

Comment: Sorry, will correct the code

Comment: @KlausD.- you are saying its a blocking call? I have tried having a client sending in a message and close it, still seeing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
import time
import socket


class TCPServer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop_thread = threading.Event()

    def startServer(self, ip="localhost", port=12345):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.server, args=(self.stop_thread,
                                                       "stop_event"))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def server(self, stop_event, arg):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.sock.listen(5)
        connection, addr = self.sock.accept()
        while not stop_event.is_set():
            data = connection.recv(50000)
            if data:
                connection.send(self.response)
        connection.close()
        self.sock.close()

    def stopServer(self):
        self.stop_thread.set()
```

so mostly minor things that accumulated.  You needed to check if event is set, not just if event was true.  You can read more on that in [event-object docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects).  That meant you never left the inner loop.  Once you leave the inner loop you need to close both connection and the socket explicitly.

Comment: @Shrikanth-n does this help?

Comment: Yes, I tried this as well. Still does not seem to work. Let me update my code with this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: what python are you using?  it works well for me on 2.7.3

Comment: Am using python 2.7.12